# Rotating an image around a fixed position - plain javascript

Tags: javascript

I've looked at several threads, and I cannot for the life of me get my image to properly rotate to the position of my mouse cursor. I can get the image to translate to the position of my mouse cursor, I know I'm close, I just don't know exactly where I am off at... below is what I have so far. The image needs to rotate at its current position and face the mouse cursor if that makes more sense... PS I am new to coding!

```js
var myGamePiece;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(50, 50, "Assets/PNG/Soldier 1/soldier1_gun.png", 10, 120, "image"); //size, source, starting location
    myGameArea.start();
    
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 1);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    if (type == "image") {
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = color;
    }

    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {

        this.width = window.innerWidth/20; //update width based on window size
        this.height = window.innerHeight/20; //update height based on window size
        
        ctx = myGameArea.context;

        if (type == "image") {


        document.onmousemove = function(e) {
            dx = e.pageX;
            dy = e.pageY;
            console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
            theta = Math.atan2(dy - this.y, dx - this.x);
            theta = theta * (180/Math.PI);
        }
        
        //console.log(theta);


            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(this.image.width/2,this.image.height/2); // updates the image origin upon rotating
            ctx.rotate(theta); // rotates the image to specified position
            ctx.drawImage(this.image,
                this.x, 
                this.y,
                this.width, this.height);
            ctx.restore();

        } else {
            console.log("failed");
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;
    }
}



function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1; 
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1; 
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1; 
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1; 
}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0; 
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
}



var keys;

setInterval(mainLoop, 50);

function mainLoop(){



document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys = (keys || []);
    keys[e.keyCode]=true;
    if (keys[37]){ // left
            moveleft();
    }

    if (keys[38]){ // up
            moveup();
    }

    if (keys[39]){ // right
           moveright();
    }

    if (keys[40]){ // down
            movedown();
    }


} , false);

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode]=false;
    stop();
clearmove();

if (keys[37]){ // left
    moveleft();
}

if (keys[38]){ // up
    moveup();
}

if (keys[39]){ // right
   moveright();
}

if (keys[40]){ // down
    movedown();
}



}, false);


}
```

Comment: I don't think you copied the code correctly ana/or completely. There's a slew of undeclared variables

Comment: should it get rotated or translated?

Comment: I have added some more of the code above, and changed a few things around